# Xubuntu 20.04 on Dell Latitude e6530: How to display time stamp in File Manager?

Tags: 20.04, filemanager, default, timestamp

I haven't found how to tell File Manager to display time stamps as default. Is that possible? So inconvenient not to have that when copying files from one location to another.

Answer (score 0):

just open File Manager and go to menu->View (select "view as detailed list").

Comment: Thanks, I had already done that, but all it shows is the date, not the time. To be sure I'm replacing an older file with a newer one, I need to know the timestamp.

Comment: For File Manager to have time available you should have Ubuntu 20.10 other else you should use another tool named Nautilus/File

Comment: Thanks antonio1. I'll see if there's a Xubuntu 20.10 as well.

Comment: @Hulda *I'll see if there's a Xubuntu 20.10 as well* No, 20.10 is End of Life. You may want to try Xubuntu 21.10.